# Not enough power to run speakers at 60ft distance?

Tags: mixer, amplifier, power

I am trying to move my powered mixer to the back of a building.  The wires have to travel 60ft to the mic's and speakers at the front of the building.  When I tried this I could not get sound to come out.  I have a Peavey PVi6500 400 watt system that is trying to feed 2 Peavey speakers.  The model of the speakers are 112H Enclosure and the serial number is 5E-02121672.  It also has 85A on it.  I assume this is 85amps.  These speakers are not powered.  My guess is not enough power to travel that distance.  Is this correct?  Any ideas on how to fix this cheap?

Comment: More likely the cables are not working or not plugged in correctly. You don't need more power to get through 50 ft of cable than you need for 2 ft.

Answer (score 1):

Balanced microphone cables can run 300ft without noticeable signal loss, so that should not be your issue. Speaker cables can easily do that distance as well.

If you got new longer cables to run the extra distance enabling you to move your mixer, I would test them to make sure they are working.

Comment: What about the source signal, is it balanced? Are the mics professional grade with balanced output?